# Powershell Missing ')' in method call

Tags: powershell

When I try and run this command I keep getting "Missing ')' in method call."

What am I misssing?

```
powershell -Command "& 
{
 if ((Get-Date -displayHint Time (GetDate)
         .AddMinutes(-15)
         .ToUniversalTime() -format HH:mm:ss) 
-lt ([datetime]::ParseExact('13:38:43', "HH:mm:ss", $null))) 
{ return 0 } 
else { return 1}'}"
```

Comment: what's with the single quote after the close bracket on return? `else { return 1}'}"`

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

1. If you used outer double quotes to wrap the command, use single quotes inside of it.
2. You have a typo: GetDate -> Get-Date
3. You can skip displayHint and get the time part with:

   (Get-Date)AddMinutes(-15).ToUniversalTime() -format 'HH:mm:ss'
4. I suggest to use the -File parameter and pass a script path when your command is longer than a simple one liner, it can save you some head ache.

Here's the full command:

```
"&
{
    if((Get-Date -displayHint Time (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15).ToUniversalTime() -format 'HH:mm:ss')  -lt 
    ([datetime]::ParseExact('13:38:43', 'HH:mm:ss', $null))) 
    {return 0} else { return 1}
}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of what you want to do, but you can try :

```
 if ((Get-Date -displayHint Time (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15).ToUniversalTime() -format HH:mm:ss) -lt ([datetime]::ParseExact('13:38:43', "HH:mm:ss", $null)))
 { return 0 } 
 else
 { return 1}
```

I replace `GetDate` by `Get-Date`.